# Error running android-NDK sample

Tags: android, android-ndk

I downloaded and Installed latest NDK package and setup eclipse as described 
in the tutorial. but when building HelloJni sample, console shows :

*android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,*

what did i miss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

It seems that NDK self extractor did not extract all of the package the first time. deleting and re extracting solve the problem. thumbs up for google crew.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. After lots of research I found one more Solution.

Disable your Antivirus Software. It's Firewall system Blocked `prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make.exe`

Just Disable Antivirus and `clean` & `rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, such question may result from the missing of the system path. You can try this way:

1)Find the directory where "make.exe" is located such as 'C:\Program Files\android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin'(your own path)

2)then go to this field: Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables->System Variables->Path.

3)add path 'C:\Program Files\android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin'  to the Path variable.(When you joint the string of Path variable, do not forget the punctuation ";")

I hope this could be helpful~

Comment: yes i think that is correct but the thing is that there is no 'make.exe' in ndk package ! and i added the path to ndk folder to PATH variable. no luck. should i install minGW ?